# Incorrect result of integration with GenerateConditions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

The `GenerateConditions->True` option of the `Integrate` command is useful
and works properly in most cases. However, there are cases when this command
works improperly. Here is one of these: the result of

```
Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x]), {x, a, b}, Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[Cot[a/2] - Cot[b/2], a^2 < a b || a b > b^2]`

is not correct if the integration range includes a zero of `Cos[x]-1`.

The result of

```
Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x]), {x, Pi/4, b}, Assumptions -> {b} \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `-Cot[b/2] + Cot[\[Pi]/8]`

is not better. The same issue in 12.3.1 on Windows 10 with `Integrate[1/(Sqrt[3] - 2*Cos[x]), {x, a, b},  Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]` etc.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The integral

```
Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}  ]
(*... does not converge on {0,2 \[Pi]}*)
```

does not converge.

That's why you have to restrict your assumptions for example to `0<a<b<2Pi` !

Comment: You open an opened door.  Thank you anyway. Could you present an automatic way to this end? TIA.